# ASP Classic - Captcha Mistype Clears Form Entry

Tags: asp-classic, recaptcha

I'm working on inserting a Google ReCaptcha for an online ASP Classic form. The captcha finally works, but I ran into one issue driving me crazy in troubleshooting.

The form is pretty long and consists of text input boxes, radio buttons, and checkboxes. If the user mistypes the captcha, the error message will appear in addition to completely clearing the form.

I managed to stop the clearing of the text input boxes upon; however, I cannot figure out how to keep the selection made by the user for the radio buttons and checkboxes.

How do I prevent a refresh from occurring if the captcha must be retried?

Anyone else run into this issue? I would think this is common with the recaptcha?

I'm new to ASP, so I have a little bit of a learning curve. Any advice or resources would be greatly appreciated to help steer way for possible solution. Thanks so much for your time, and I look forward to hearing soon.

Comment: I was looking into this solution, but I'm not able to get this to work...http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=76928

Answer (score 2):

Was able to find solution through this reading on ASP Request Object, Form Collection. If interested, the following link can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ref_request.asp